# The Gradle build-upload-run cycle takes 10-20 seconds - on a fast machine. Is there any way to make that faster?

Tags: android

The oft-quoted advice is to add the following lines to your local or global `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Although that speeds up the process considerably, it still takes a good 10 to 20 seconds to see the results of a code change. This is far from the instant feedback that you get in web development.

Seems like installing your app is the biggest bottleneck, but are there any other ways to speed up the edit-build-upload-install-run cycle? Or is this as good as it gets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If testing on an ARM-based emulator, turn on Virtual Mode on your machine, use an intel based image, and use the intel based Emulator.
- Or better yet, use an actual hardware device to test on.

I just felt this needed to be said (just in case you didn't actual test on an actual device).

- Measure where the bottleneck is, before you try optimizing the process.
- For Graddle itself, install some of your dependencies locally, so that they don't need to be fetched from the web.
- Make your initial apk smaller than it needs to be (during the development phase).
- Tell Eclipse/Studio launcher to launch the Activity you're currently testing (to minimize the number of activities you have to go tap through to get to the one you're testing).
- Upgrade your internet speed